# How to format Date Time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a date timestamp coming in this format `2021-02-08T19:36:47.000+0000`. How can I format this in JavaScript in `DD-MM-YYYY Hh:mm` format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) might help you as this is answered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download `moment.js` and include to your file
then you can use like this

```
moment("2021-02-08T19:36:47.000+0000).format("DD-MM-YYYY Hh:mm")
```

I usually use this in my every project
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js

Answer (score -1):

This is plain Javascript

```js
// 2021-02-08T19:36:47.000+0000
function formatDate(date) {
  var d = new Date(date),
    minutes = ':' + d.getMinutes(),
    hours = ' ' + d.getHours(),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = '-' + d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) {
    month = '-0' + month;
  } else if (month.length < 3) {
    month = '-' + month;
  }

  if (day.length < 2)
    day = '0' + day;

  // DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm
  return [day, month, year, hours, minutes].join('');
}

console.log(formatDate("2021-02-08T19:36:47.000+0000"))
```